# How do i redirect https to http without htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have a website that redirects all requests to HTTPS.
I tried modifying htaccess but it ignores it.
Could it be that there is something else that is overriding the htaccess file?
How do i redirect https to http without htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>
```